# Unregister COM by C#

Tags: c#, dll, registry

I created a COM component in C# for calling it from excel. I am able to access it from VBA. Now I want to un-register it completely. What steps should I follow? (Gacutil gives an error - Assembly not found).
PS: Wanna do it using a program

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to run `regasm /u [dll file]`.

Comment: Thanks, but I am still able to access the file from Excel VBA: Tools -> References -> Browse 'select .tlb file' and I am able to access the properties. I dont want that :(